# Lazy Classes Includes PHP

Tags: php, autoload, glob, spl-autoload-register

I use a autoloader to include classes. What i'm doing right now is using "glob" to read different dir's and push them in an array. Is there a better solution to this?

```
$path = './';

$files = array_merge(
glob($path.'includes/classes/system/*.class.php'),
glob($path.'includes/classes/system/baseclasses/*.class.php'),
glob($path.'includes/classes/system/systementities/*.class.php'));
```

EDIT:

I use this inside an autoload class. The problem is that I have to search for the files with glob. Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoloading will be triggered whenever you are trying to use a class that isn't know to PHP. If you use `include`/`require`, PHP will go through all the directories you specified for your `include_path` in PHP.ini, so there should no reason to use `glob`. In your case, it should be sufficient to set the `include_path` to

```
/path/to/includes/classes/system/
```

The *fastest* way to include files would be to use a [class2file map](https://github.com/theseer/Autoload). However, this requires you to create such a map and keep it updated when you modify your application.

Comment: But here I need the files too. So the code above isn't changed. I already use spl_autoload_register (as the tags reveal)

Comment: What do you mean "I need the files"?  If you need a map because you think searching on the include_path is slow, consider generating the map using whatever strategy, and caching it somewhere (simple file, APC, memcache).

Comment: Sounds better, i'll give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

PHP has already solved this problem for you. Use PHP's [built-in autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php). Never roll your own when the language/framework provides it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function __autoload($class) {
  $classfile = $class.'.class.php';
  $path = './includes/classes/system/';
  if (is_file($path.$classfile)) require_once($path.$classfile);
  if (is_file($path.'baseclasses/'.$classfile)) require_once($path.'baseclasses/'.$classfile);
  if (is_file($path.'systementities/'.$classfile)) require_once($path.'systementities/'.$classfile);
}
```

...which is still not the greatest way, but it gets you around using glob().  If you are commonly loading all of your systementities there should be a hard-coded require() list in a boot/config script.  There are a lot of options on how to organize and fetch class files.  To reduce the time searching for scripts you could think of your filetree as an interface.  For the sake of simplicity, you could put all non-mandatory classes in the same folder, reducing the is_file() calls down to one.

In my system I have object classes grouped in folders with their respective control scripts and views.  My __autoload() function has a simpler job --

```
$classfile = $path.$class.'/'.$class.'_class.php';
if (is_file($classfile)) require_once($classfile);
```

Comment: I use a singleton class where I store the files, so I only have to do an isset check instead of the is_file check